# Jenkins running tests in parallel on different nodes in Jenkins gives me No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was having the following script running properly on one Jenkins:

```
    def serenityBatches = [:]

pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '6', description: 'Number of test batches that should runindividually, either parallel or batch after batch', name: 'batchCount')
        string(defaultValue: '1', description: 'Number of tests/browsers that can run simultaniously on one node', name: 'forkCount')
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clean workspace') {

            steps {
                withMaven(){ sh "mvn clean" }
            }
        }
        stage('Create batches') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def batchCount = params.batchCount.toInteger()
                    def forkCount = params.forkCount.toInteger()

                    setJobDescription( batchCount, forkCount )

                    for (int i = 1; i <= batchCount; i++) {
                        def batchNumber = i
                        def batchName = "batch${batchNumber}"
                        serenityBatches[batchName] = {
                            node {
                                stage("batch${batchNumber} checkout") {
                                    cleanWs()
                                    checkoutFromSvn()
                                }
                                stage("batch${batchNumber} testing") {
                                    runTests(batchNumber, batchCount, forkCount)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Execute tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel serenityBatches
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Generate Report') {
            steps {
                collectReportsFromAllBatches()
                aggregateReports()
                publishReport()
                zulipNotification stream: 'xxy', topic: 'AutoTests'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        changed {
            script {
                // report back to normal after failure
               if(hudson.model.Result.FAILURE.equals(currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result)) {
                  zulipNotification stream: 'xxy', topic: 'AutoTests'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void checkoutFromSvn() {
    checkout changelog: false, 
        scm: [ $class: 'SubversionSCM', 
            locations: [[   cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
            credentialsId: 'someID', 
            depthOption: 'infinity', 
            ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
            local: '.', 
            remote: 'https://whatever',
            clearWorkspace: true
            ]], 
        quietOperation: true, 
        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
        ]
}

void runTests(batchNumber, batchCount, forkCount) {
    try {
        withMaven(){
            sh "mvn clean"
            sh "rm -rf target/site/serenity"
            sh "mvn -U verify -Dparallel.tests=${forkCount} -Dserenity.batch.count=${batchCount} -Dserenity.batch.number=${batchNumber}"
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw e
    } finally {
        stash name: getStashId(batchNumber), excludes: "**", allowEmpty: true
        stash name: getStashId(batchNumber), includes: "target/site/serenity/**/*", allowEmpty: true
    }
}

String getStashId(int batchNumber) {
    return "$JOB_NAME".replace('/','_')+"-$BUILD_NUMBER-batch-${batchNumber}"
}

/** unstash each of the batches **/
void collectReportsFromAllBatches() {
    script {
        def batchCount = params.batchCount.toInteger()
        for (int batchNumber = 1; batchNumber <= batchCount; batchNumber++) {
            def stashName = getStashId(batchNumber)
            unstash stashName
        }
    }
}

void aggregateReports() {
    withMaven(){ sh "mvn serenity:aggregate" }
}

/** publish the Serenity report **/
void publishReport() {
    publishHTML(target: [
            reportName : 'Serenity Report',
            reportDir:   'target/site/serenity',
            reportFiles: 'index.html',
            keepAll:     true,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            allowMissing: false
    ])
}

void setJobDescription(int batchCount, int forkCount) {
    currentBuild.description = "batches:$batchCount forks:$forkCount"
}
```

But now we are moving to another Jenkins where there are specific nodes for testing (chromium) so I am trying to adapt the script to run there. I can run the original script there but obviously the tests will run on random nodes so they fail.
The following script gives me a "No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps" I dont quite understand. Already tried a lot of different combinations... No success yet.

```
def serenityBatches = [:]

pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '6', description: 'Number of test batches that should runindividually, either parallel or batch after batch', name: 'batchCount')
        string(defaultValue: '1', description: 'Number of tests/browsers that can run simultaniously on one node', name: 'forkCount')
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clean workspace') {

            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'Maven 3.6.1'){ sh "mvn clean" }
            }
        }
        stage('Create batches') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def batchCount = params.batchCount.toInteger()
                    def forkCount = params.forkCount.toInteger()

                    setJobDescription( batchCount, forkCount )

                    for (int i = 1; i <= batchCount; i++) {
                        def batchNumber = i
                        def batchName = "batch${batchNumber}"
                        serenityBatches[batchName] = {

                                stage("batch${batchNumber} checkout") {
                                    agent { label 'chrome' }
                                    steps {
                                    cleanWs()
                                    checkoutFromSvn()
                                    runTests(batchNumber, batchCount, forkCount)
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    parallel serenityBatches
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Generate Report') {
            steps {
                collectReportsFromAllBatches()
                aggregateReports()
                publishReport()
                zulipNotification stream: 'xxy', topic: 'AutoTests'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            zulipNotification stream: 'xxy', topic: 'AutoTests'
        }
        changed {
            script {
                // report back to normal after failure
               if(hudson.model.Result.FAILURE.equals(currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result)) {
                  zulipNotification stream: 'xxy', topic: 'AutoTests'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void checkoutFromSvn() {
    checkout changelog: false, 
        scm: [ $class: 'SubversionSCM', 
            locations: [[   cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
            credentialsId: 'someID', 
            depthOption: 'infinity', 
            ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
            local: '.', 
            remote: 'https://whatever',
            clearWorkspace: true
            ]], 
        quietOperation: true, 
        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
        ]
}

void runTests(batchNumber, batchCount, forkCount) {
    try {
        withMaven(maven: 'Maven 3.6.1'){
            sh "mvn clean"
            sh "rm -rf target/site/serenity"
            sh "mvn -U verify -Dparallel.tests=${forkCount} -Dtest=LoggedInUserStaysLoggedInTDTest -Dserenity.batch.count=${batchCount} -Dserenity.batch.number=${batchNumber} -Dheadless.mode=true"
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw e
    } finally {
        stash name: getStashId(batchNumber), excludes: "**", allowEmpty: true
        stash name: getStashId(batchNumber), includes: "target/site/serenity/**/*", allowEmpty: true
    }
}

String getStashId(int batchNumber) {
    return "$JOB_NAME".replace('/','_')+"-$BUILD_NUMBER-batch-${batchNumber}"
}

/** unstash each of the batches **/
void collectReportsFromAllBatches() {
    script {
        def batchCount = params.batchCount.toInteger()
        for (int batchNumber = 1; batchNumber <= batchCount; batchNumber++) {
            def stashName = getStashId(batchNumber)
            unstash stashName
        }
    }
}

void aggregateReports() {
    withMaven(maven: 'Maven 3.6.1'){ sh "mvn serenity:aggregate" }
}

/** publish the Serenity report **/
void publishReport() {
    publishHTML(target: [
            reportName : 'Serenity Report',
            reportDir:   'target/site/serenity',
            reportFiles: 'index.html',
            keepAll:     true,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
            allowMissing: false
    ])
}

void setJobDescription(int batchCount, int forkCount) {
    currentBuild.description = "batches:$batchCount forks:$forkCount"
}
```

Comment: It appears that you have a `stage` nested inside `script` which then means the `agent` is nested inside the `script` block. This is syntactically ambiguous and probably not allowed, which is likely why you are seeing that error. Try closing the `script` block prior to the `stage` and opening a new one afterward.

Comment: I am not sure where you mean to do that. I need the script block to be able to add batches to the collection. If you could provide an example as answer I will give it a shot.

Comment: Ok it just occurred to me you are probably using scripted pipeline and not declarative. I was thrown off by the use of `agent` instead of `node`. You are using scripted syntax and not declarative, correct?

Comment: I was in the understanding that this is declarative. Although I am often confused about what is what...  Actually I dont mind which one.. It just should work. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to define your agent with ***node(label){ ... }*** block embracing the ***stage*** block.

Example:

```
serenityBatches[batchName] = {
    node('chrome') {
        stage("batch${batchNumber} checkout") {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                checkoutFromSvn()
                runTests(batchNumber, batchCount, forkCount)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice shot. I already tried that. That is why there is the empty line on that position. ;-) 
But gives me the same error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps`

Comment: You got an empty line *and* an **agent { label 'chrome' }** defined inside of the *steps{}* block. Make sure that you test my solution *without* the **agent { label 'chrome' }**.

Comment: You where right about that. Now I'm getting a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps`.  Thanks. Trying around from here.
```
serenityBatches[batchName] = {
node('chrome') {
  stage("batch${batchNumber} checkout") {
    steps {
       cleanWs()
       checkoutFromSvn()
       runTests(batchNumber, batchCount, forkCount)
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So now this is a "scripted Pipeline" right? Because for declarative Pipeline the example clearly states "agent" not "node"
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/